# Can Connectify Change Traffic Limits

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection, connectify

I have an ethernet connection from dormitory server at home where I have a traffic limit of 4 gb per month. My neighbour has recently installed the software `Connectify Pro v.9.3` in his PC. Now, he says his Internet traffic became unlimited.

Can software such as Connectify get around such traffic limits?

If so, how is this possible for it to change the counting of the Internet usage?

Comment: It can't do that (unless you schools IT sucks *really* bad, and even then I'm not sure how it could affect their traffic controls).  How do you know he's now got unlimited traffic?

Comment: We are enjoying this Hotspot for a Month and it is not ending. We were just curious how it is possible?

Comment: Maybe the school doesn't ACTUALLY block you at 4GB (exactly), or they allow some lenience.  I'd discuss it with the school's IT. I'm voting to close this since it's not about a home network/PC problem, and we'd just be guessing what your school's IT has implemented.

Comment: Thank you Thechi007 for an answer but as I said we might have exceeded the traffic limit multiple times since he is sharing it for a month. I am hoping that there will be some other ideas about this phenomenon.

Comment: Since Connictify can share multiple connections and devices simultaneously, is it possible that it has been utilizing bandwidth from someone's mobile phone as part of the network?  Also, how do you know it's unlimited (besides the lack of shutting it off)?  Do you have a site where you can view total usage?

Comment: Yes, there is a site where you can see the usage of The Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 1 size fits all solution - it is certainly not possible for a device to get round properly set up traffic limits.    Its very difficult to comment meaningfully unless more is known about the network.

If the network is set up by idiots its possible that traffic is limited based on MAC address and that this software is cycling through MAC addresses.  Its less likely (but not impossible) that the device is setting up a tunnel to an endpoint which is not byte-counted by your network administrator.

Yet another explanation is a mis configured port or bribed system administrator.